# How to implement a transaction for the cache (Apache Ignite)?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, ignite

I need to implement the transaction for the cache Ignite via SpringTransactionManager using the Transactional annotation. This is necessary for indicate the order of execution of aspects for the transaction and audit.
That's how I did it.

**IgniteConfig:**

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
public class IgniteConfig {

@Value("${ignite.cache.name}")
private String igniteCacheName;

@Autowired
private IgniteIpFinderProvider ipFinderProvider;

@Bean
public Ignite ignite() {
    return Ignition.start(igniteConfiguration());
}

private IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration() {
    IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration = new IgniteConfiguration();
    igniteConfiguration.setGridName(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    igniteConfiguration.setDiscoverySpi(getDiscoverySpi());
    igniteConfiguration.setCacheConfiguration(getCacheConfig());
    return igniteConfiguration;
}

@Bean
@Qualifier(value = "transactionManager")
public SpringTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    SpringTransactionManager transactionManager = new SpringTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setConfiguration(igniteConfiguration());
    return transactionManager;
}

private DiscoverySpi getDiscoverySpi() {
    TcpDiscoverySpi discoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
    discoverySpi.setIpFinder(ipFinderProvider.getIpFinder());
    return discoverySpi;
}

private CacheConfiguration getCacheConfig() {
    CacheConfiguration<String, String> cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration<>();
    cacheConfiguration.setName(igniteCacheName);
    cacheConfiguration.setIndexedTypes(String.class, String.class);
    cacheConfiguration.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
    cacheConfiguration.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
    cacheConfiguration.setBackups(2);
    return cacheConfiguration;
}
}
```

**Repository:**

```
@Transactional(transactionManager = "transactionManager", rollbackForClassName = "Exception")
public String putAndGet(String userName, String userSessionData) {
    ignite.<String, String>cache(igniteCacheName).put(userName, userSessionData);

    method();

    return ignite.<String, String>cache(igniteCacheName).get(userName);
}

void method() throws CacheException {
    throw new CacheException();
}
```

But the problem is that the rollback operation does not work.

Who knows how to implement a transaction with Spring Transaction in Ignite?

I will be glad to any help!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "rollback operation does not work"? Can you clarify?

Comment: @Valentin Kulichenko, when throws CacheException, the data remains in the cache, and with rollback the cache must remain empty

Comment: Can you provide your test? I can't reproduce the behavior and actually Ignite has a test for this particular case. Not sure why it's not working for you as expected.